# pulumi/aws - create resources in newly created oranizations account

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code, aws-organizations

I'm currently bootstrapping an AWS organizations setup using pulumi. (prod/dev/... accounts, security accounts, ci access, etc. - I think in azure this concept is called "landing zone" but since this name refers to a specific product on AWS, I'm not using it here.)

What I want to do is

1. Create a bunch of new subaccounts `aws.organizations.Account`
2. Deploy resources ***into*** these subaccounts (example: ci access, users, roles, etc)

Here's what I tried - From what I remember, the "same" code works in terraform:

```
const account = new organizations.Account("account", {
  roleName: "some-role-name-for-the-parent-account-to-assume",
  ...
})

const provider = new Provider("subaccount-provider", {
  assumeRole: {
    roleArn: `arn:aws:iam::${account.id}:role/${account.roleName}`
  }
})

const otherResource = new WhateverAWSResource(
  "other-resource",
  { ... },
  // the role assumed by the provider will result in the resource being created in the subaccount  
  { provider }
)
```

The issue now is that:

- The `Account` instance does not expose the `roleArn`
- String interpolation is not allowed in pulumi since `account.id` and `account.roleName` are of type `Output<string>`

**Question:** Is there a way to make something like this work? Preferably

- Without explicitly splitting the project/stacks at the `-.yaml` level. This would require additional plumbing and feels very unelegant since it would introduce a lot of noise in the repo structure.
- Without using the automation API.

I think the automation API is fine to make it work but it seems kind of non-ideomatic for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String interpolation is not allowed in pulumi since account.id and account.roleName are of type Output

You could use `pulumi.all` to map an array of outputs into an output that wraps the array (works similarly to `Promise.all`).

**For strings, `pulumi.interpolate` or `pulumi.concat` might be even better (see [the docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#outputs-and-strings))**.

Example (`pulumi.interpolate`):

```js
const provider = new Provider("subaccount-provider", {
  assumeRole: {
    roleArn: pulumi.interpolate`arn:aws:iam::${account.id}:role/${account.roleName}`
  }
})
```