# Error when creating resources in newly created oranizations account: "Assume Role: role ARN not set"

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code, aws-organizations

I am trying to implement the very [same strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74115692/pulumi-aws-create-resources-in-newly-created-oranizations-account), except that I am using Python (with `Output.concat`):

```
import pulumi
import pulumi_aws as aws

stack = pulumi.get_stack()

account = aws.organizations.Account(
    f"{stack}-account",
    email="master@example.com",
    role_name=f"{stack}-account-role",
)

provider = aws.Provider(
    f"{stack}-account-provider",
    assume_role={'role_arn': pulumi.Output.concat("arn:aws:iam::", account.id, ":role/", account.role_name)},
)

aws.iam.User("new-iam-user", path='/', opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(provider=provider))
```

In my root account, I have created a new IAM user that has administrator access. When using the credentials of that user, I am running into the following error when doing `pulumi up`:

```
Diagnostics:
  aws:iam:User (new-iam-user):
    error: unable to validate AWS credentials.
    Details: Assume Role: role ARN not set
    
    Make sure you have:
    
         • Set your AWS region, e.g. `pulumi config set aws:region us-west-2`
         • Configured your AWS credentials as per https://pulumi.io/install/aws.html
         You can also set these via cli using `aws configure`.
```

Checking the [role_name](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/organizations/account/#role_name_python) poperty, I would assume that should work. What am I missing?